# Android Relative Layout Padding Issues

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, padding

I have looked up similar problems but their solutions aren't working. My Relative Layout is adding Left padding.

This is my XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="0dp"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:padding="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewUserProfile"
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_t" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserProfileName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewUserProfile"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserProfileHighlights"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageViewUserProfile"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewUserProfileName"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I removed the parenting LinearLayout to double check that the left padding was coming from atleast the RelativeLayout block. I have tried most of what worked for other people. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation for an image =(
Basically, when I select the Relative Layout from the graphical Layout on eclipse android xml editor, it selects the whole width of the parent (Linear Layout) but it adds a few dp for left padding, thus my image is supposed to be on the top left corner, but there is   a bit of space from the left

Comment: Can you email me a picture RSenApps@gmail.com?

Comment: Email sent, I can send a larger photo if more information is needed. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ImageView set alignParentTop and alignParentLeft to true also remove the LinearLayout, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Tried align Top and Left to true to no avail. I am adding two fragments below the relative layout that I want to split the screen through the middle, that is why I put a parent Linear Layout

Comment: If you remove the 2 textviews does the problem persist?

Comment: Yes the Image was the first item on my relative layout, and since the beginning it has had that padding

Comment: If you remove all properties of the listview and change to wrap_contents, does it still happen? Also often the renderer in Eclipse is off, so try using the emulator

Comment: By listview do you mean the relative layout? Also I am debugging it on my phone (galaxy s2 android 2.3 )

Comment: @Mathias Sorry, I was answering 2 questions at the same time, I meant ImageView

Comment: No worries, I removed everything and it made it a lot smaller however it got rid of the padding, I am going to re size the actual image to fit the original image size. Thanks

Comment: I think the issue was related to this:  android:adjustViewBounds="true" Goodluck, please accept my answer if it helped :)